# Can I change the default definition displayed by Swagger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

[image]

Can I change the default definition from 'default' to my own one. I would like the page to load and instead of it loading the 'default' it would load mine which is just called 'swagger' in this case:

[image]

I am using Spring fox and Spring boot. This is my Swagger Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerDocumentationConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.openet.usage.trigger"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private static Predicate<String> matchPathRegex(final String... pathRegexs) {
        return new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(String input) {
                for (String pathRegex : pathRegexs) {
                    if (input.matches(pathRegex)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/config/swagger.json").
                        addResourceLocations("classpath:/config");
                registry
                        .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
                registry
                        .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change this behavior, but it looks more like a hack.

The `SwaggerResourcesProvider` is responsible for providing info for the dropdown list. First, implement this interface. Second, add the `Primary` annotation to your class to become the main implementation that should be used instead of the default `InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider` class. But it still makes sense to reuse definitions provided by InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider and that is why it should be injected.

The last part is to implement the overridden `get` method and change to the list you want to display. This example should display only one definition named `swagger`.

```
// other annotations
@Primary
public class SwaggerDocumentationConfig implements SwaggerResourcesProvider { 
   private final InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider resourcesProvider;

   @Inject
   public MySwaggerConfig(InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider resourcesProvider) {
       this.resourcesProvider = resourcesProvider;
   }

   @Override
   public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
       return resourcesProvider.get().stream()
           .filter(r -> "swagger".equals(r.getName()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   // the rest of the configuration
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did a redirect in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void redirectRootToSwaggerDocs(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("/my-api/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=swagger");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found is just to make the groupName rank highly alphabetically. Such as "1 swagger", "a swagger" or "-> swagger".

```java
...
return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
    .groupName("-> swagger");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
        .groupName("<what u want>")
...
```

just set a default group name.